# What do you need to make the most basic jQuery script run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have this in the head tag: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.js"></script>` in order to load jquery.

Then I have this code right before the closing body tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Ready");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This script works in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work when I try to run it in my browser (Firefox and Chrome). I've tried running it from a local file then uploaded to my website in case that affected anything.

So what else could be making it so this simple script doesn't run?

Solved: There was another script running on the document ready event using the shortcut '$(function())'. I didn't realize you couldn't use that twice in different scripts. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: Any error in Console??

Comment: Just a guess - is your jquery loaded after this function? You need to load jQuery itself before any jQuery runs so that it recognizes it.

Comment: Here is the only one that could be related: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: @itamar I am not exactly positive to the load order of the scripts, but I have the link to load jquery in the head and the script I'm trying to run in the body, so I think it should be loaded.

Comment: if your website isn't https, try changing https to http - otherwise if you haven't missed something in the question, it looks like it should run

Comment: Just for grins, try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your head tag if it is not already there. And can you show us the full html?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Explicit character sets aren't required for executing javascript.  It would assume the local charset.

Comment: @JamesSmith can you show the HTML?

Comment: @Nilpo, yeah I didnt think it would have this effect, I only mentioned in response the OP's comment above. I'm admittedly not very knowledgeable of character set logic. Thanks

Comment: God damn it. There was another script running on the document ready event using the shortcut '$(function())'. I didn't realize you couldn't use that twice in different scripts. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: Its better to add the solution as an answer. There is an option to answer yourself. Currently the status of this question is unsolved. @JamesSmith

Comment: Yep I added my answer, but it says I can't accept in for another 2 days.

Comment: @JamesSmith That doesn't address the problem.  You can run as many scripts as you like.  What is the output of the JavaScript console?

Comment: Any specific reason why you're using version 1.8 of jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in your other scripts.  Another portion of Javascript is producing an error and should be visible in your console.

Here's a sample showing that you can bind to the document ready event more than once.  I'll even use multiple syntaxes.

```js
// The first three examples are syntactically identical. They will fire in
// the order in which they appear, also known as FIFO or First In, First Out.
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Ready one");
});

$(function() {
    alert("Ready two");
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("Ready three");
});

// Note: this syntax should fire first, only requires the jQuery object be loaded
(function($) { 
    alert("Ready four");
})(jQuery);

// and for good measure...this syntax should always fire last
$(window).load(function() {
    alert("Ready five");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I want to recreate the OP's issue, I only have to create an exception in the first event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Ready one");
    // creating an error here should halt execution before the second function begins
    throw "some error";
});

$(function() {
    alert("Ready two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And to prove it, here's is the exact same snippet with the throw line commented out, and working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Ready one");
    // creating an error here should halt execution before the second function begins
    //throw "some error";
});

$(function() {
    alert("Ready two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another script running on the document ready event using the shortcut '$(function())'. I didn't realize you couldn't use that twice in different scripts. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: This surely doesn't address the real problem, which is probably the other script throwing an exception. You indeed can bind more than one function to the document ready event and they'll run in FIFO order, unless an exception stops the script.

Comment: @matpop Agreed.  You definitely CAN have more than one instance.  You can bind to any event more than once.  That's the beauty of event-driven scripting.

Comment: No, you definitely can have multiple `ready` event handlers, no matter the syntax.

Answer (score -3):

It should work. Try adding type="text/javascript" to script tag. and make sure your custom script is after your have load the jquery.js

Comment: the question states that the script tag that loads jquery is in `head` ... and the user script is at the bottom of `body` ... so, the second part to your answer is redundant

Comment: "text/javascript" is assumed in all modern browsers.  It's not even needed in HTML5.